# Access Violation exception in WPF application and DirectX rasterizer

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, directx

I have a WPF application that after some trivial playing around (opening and closing some application controls) is crashed. when I open the crash dump file I see that the exception is

```
FAULTING_IP: 
rgb9rast!D3D8RGBRast::CRGBContext::PackGenVertex+b4
000007fe`f7625b88 428b0c10        mov     ecx,dword ptr [rax+r10]

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffffffffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)
ExceptionAddress: 000007fef7625b88 (rgb9rast!D3D8RGBRast::CRGBContext::PackGenVertex+0x00000000000000b4)
ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
Parameter[0]: 0000000000000000
Parameter[1]: 000000009f011620
Attempt to read from address 000000009f011620
```

which indicated access violation error in directx rasterization and the faulting thread stack trace is (I omitted call addresses)

```
rgb9rast!D3D8RGBRast::CRGBContext::PackGenVertex+0xb4
rgb9rast!D3D8RGBRast::CRGBContext::DoDrawOneGenIndexedPrimitive+0x72b
rgb9rast!D3D8RGBRast::CRGBContext::DP2DrawIndexedPrimitive2+0x1d4
rgb9rast!DX8SDDIFW::SDP2MFnParser::ParseDP2<DX8SDDIFW::CStdDrawPrimitives2<D3D8RGBRast::CRGBContext,D3D8RGBRast::CRGBStateSet,D3D8RGBRast::static_hash_map<unsigned long,D3D8RGBRast::CRGBStateSet,32,D3D8RGBRast::hash<unsigned long>,std::equal_to<unsigned long>,D3D8RGBRast::allocator<std::pair<unsigned long const ,D3D8RGBRast::CRGBStateSet> > >,DX8SDDIFW::CDP2DataWrap<D3D8RGBRast::SDP2NextCmdExt>,D3D8RGBRast::block<long (__cdecl D3D8RGBRast::CRGBContext::*)(DX8SDDIFW::CDP2DataWrap<D3D8RGBRast::SDP2NextCmdExt> & __ptr64,_D3DHAL_DP2COMMAND const * __ptr64,void const * __ptr64) __ptr64,89>,D3D8RGBRast::block<long (__cdecl D3D8RGBRast::CRGBContext::*)(_D3DHAL_DP2COMMAND const * __ptr64,void * __ptr64) __ptr64,89> >::TMFnCaller,D3D8RGBRast::block<long (__cdecl D3D8RGBRast::CRGBContext::*)(DX8SDDIFW::CDP2DataWrap<D3D8RGBRast::SDP2NextCmdExt> & __ptr64,_D3DHAL_DP2COMMAND const * __ptr64,void const * __ptr64) __ptr64,89>,DX8SDDIFW::CConstDP2CmdIterator<D3D8RGBRast::SDP2NextCmdExt> >+0x69
rgb9rast!DX8SDDIFW::CStdDrawPrimitives2<D3D8RGBRast::CRGBContext,D3D8RGBRast::CRGBStateSet,D3D8RGBRast::static_hash_map<unsigned long,D3D8RGBRast::CRGBStateSet,32,D3D8RGBRast::hash<unsigned long>,std::equal_to<unsigned long>,D3D8RGBRast::allocator<std::pair<unsigned long const ,D3D8RGBRast::CRGBStateSet> > >,DX8SDDIFW::CDP2DataWrap<D3D8RGBRast::SDP2NextCmdExt>,D3D8RGBRast::block<long (__cdecl D3D8RGBRast::CRGBContext::*)(DX8SDDIFW::CDP2DataWrap<D3D8RGBRast::SDP2NextCmdExt> & __ptr64,_D3DHAL_DP2COMMAND const * __ptr64,void const * __ptr64) __ptr64,89>,D3D8RGBRast::block<long (__cdecl D3D8RGBRast::CRGBContext::*)(_D3DHAL_DP2COMMAND const * __ptr64,void * __ptr64) __ptr64,89> >::DrawPrimitives2+0x345
rgb9rast!DX8SDDIFW::CSubDriver<D3D8RGBRast::CRGBDriver,D3D8RGBRast::CRGBContext,D3D8RGBRast::CRGBSurfAllocator,D3D8RGBRast::CRGBPerDDrawData,D3D8RGBRast::set<D3D8RGBRast::CRGBContext * __ptr64,std::less<D3D8RGBRast::CRGBContext * __ptr64>,D3D8RGBRast::allocator<D3D8RGBRast::CRGBContext * __ptr64> >,D3D8RGBRast::map<_DDRAWI_DIRECTDRAW_LCL * __ptr64,D3D8RGBRast::CRGBPerDDrawData,std::less<_DDRAWI_DIRECTDRAW_LCL * __ptr64>,D3D8RGBRast::allocator<std::pair<_DDRAWI_DIRECTDRAW_LCL * __ptr64 const,D3D8RGBRast::CRGBPerDDrawData> > >,D3D8RGBRast::set<D3D8RGBRast::IRGBSurface * __ptr64,std::less<D3D8RGBRast::IRGBSurface * __ptr64>,D3D8RGBRast::allocator<D3D8RGBRast::IRGBSurface * __ptr64> >,DX8SDDIFW::SFakeEntryPointHook<D3D8RGBRast::CRGBDriver> >::DrawPrimitives2+0x26
d3d9!SwDrawPrimitives2+0x7c
d3d9!CD3DDDIDX8::FlushStates+0x161
d3d9!CD3DBase::FlushStatesNoThrow+0x22
d3d9!CVertexBuffer::Lock+0xce
d3d9!CVertexBufferMT::Lock+0x7e
d3d9!CTLStream::Lock+0x6d
d3d9!CD3DDDIDX8::StartPrimTL+0x3b
d3d9!CD3DDDIDX8::ProcessIndexedPrimitiveC+0xa0
d3d9!CD3DBase::DrawIndexedPrimitive+0x489
wpfgfx_v0400!CD3DDeviceLevel1::DrawIndexedTriangleList+0x49
wpfgfx_v0400!CHw3DGeometryRenderer<unsigned long>::Render+0x152
wpfgfx_v0400!CHwShader::FixedFunctionDrawMesh3D+0x158
wpfgfx_v0400!CHwShader::DrawMesh3D+0x88
wpfgfx_v0400!CHwSurfaceRenderTarget::DrawMesh3D+0x1fb
wpfgfx_v0400!CHw3DSoftwareSurface::DrawMesh3D+0x38
wpfgfx_v0400!CSwRenderTargetSurface::DrawMesh3D+0x49
wpfgfx_v0400!CMetaRenderTarget::DrawMesh3D+0xee
wpfgfx_v0400!CModelRenderWalker::RealizeMaterialAndRender+0x17a
wpfgfx_v0400!CModelRenderWalker::ProcessMaterialAndRender+0x160
wpfgfx_v0400!CModelRenderWalker::RenderGeometryModel3D+0x11b
wpfgfx_v0400!CModelRenderWalker::PreSubgraph+0x19
wpfgfx_v0400!CModelIterator::Walk+0x64
wpfgfx_v0400!CModelRenderWalker::RenderModels+0x70
wpfgfx_v0400!CRender3DContext::PreSubgraph+0xd3
wpfgfx_v0400!CGraphIterator::Walk+0x4b
wpfgfx_v0400!CRender3DContext::Render+0xd9
wpfgfx_v0400!CDrawingContext::Render3D+0x277
wpfgfx_v0400!CMilViewport3DVisual::RenderContent+0x50
wpfgfx_v0400!CDrawingContext::PreSubgraph+0x766
wpfgfx_v0400!CGraphIterator::Walk+0x4b
wpfgfx_v0400!CDrawingContext::DrawVisualTree+0x23d
wpfgfx_v0400!CDrawingContext::Render+0x393
wpfgfx_v0400!CSlaveHWndRenderTarget::Render+0x206
wpfgfx_v0400!CRenderTargetManager::Render+0x4d
wpfgfx_v0400!CComposition::Render+0x28
wpfgfx_v0400!CComposition::ProcessComposition+0x13a
wpfgfx_v0400!CComposition::Compose+0x51
wpfgfx_v0400!CPartitionThread::RenderPartition+0x28
wpfgfx_v0400!CPartitionThread::Run+0x61
wpfgfx_v0400!CPartitionThread::ThreadMain+0x1c
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x1d
```

this happens on only some PCs where I check the application. all have .Net 4.5 and Directx 11.
 what can be the cause for that? when debugging / investigating the dump file I can't see any managed code that can lead to that.
the only hint I have is that I have some 3D content in the app, which can be related to some of the 3D rendering methods in the faulting thread stack trace.

Comment: Were you able to understand what's going on? Was this fixed? I think we have the same stack trace in our dump file. Any help will be appreciated (even if you don't remember :) )

Comment: @ChuckNorris Is your RenderOptions.ProcessRenderMode set to RenderMode.SoftwareOnly, or are you using RDP to access the application, by any chance?

Comment: @LynnCrumbling - Yes, I think our WPF program's ProcessRenderMode is set to RenderMode.SoftwareOnly. (it can be changed in Settings, but default value is True)
I'm not sure if users were using RDP when they experienced application crash with this exception in dump file though, it could happen in their own machine.

Comment: I see this question also mentions this possible issue, but there is nothing about why it happens and how to prevent it when you are using RenderMode.SoftwareOnly.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/361264/wpf-application-using-model3d-crashes-when-applica.html

Comment: @ChuckNorris As a partial solution/test, trying turning off software rendering, and see if you still experience the crash. Also, if it were me, I'd try creating an [MCVE] that repros this. I realize that'll take you a lot of time to rip out code slowly to get it down to something small, but likely will get you moving towards the cause.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling Thanks. We may be forced to keep that setting however because of some other issues in Virtual Machines. According to this SO question, the VS forum post and our own experience - there were at least 3 reported cases of this issue. It would be really good if Microsoft would troubleshoot this...

Comment: Re: "this happens on only some PCs where I check the application." What is the amount of available and free memory on the PCs the incur this problem compared to those that do not. Could this be a memory constraint problem?

Comment: There was a related (but now deleted as "abandoned") question that didn't get answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57219993/app-frozen-inside-wpfgfx-v0400-dll-utility-polygonbounds-and-utility-pathgeometr   Maybe there is a slim chance some info there is relevant or useful.

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs Side note - I don't think Oren would be able to see that with <10k rep.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling true, not sure what could be done about that though? Seemed better to point it out rather than not.

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs I guess you could drop it in a gist or a pastebin and put the link as a comment on here?

Comment: @LynnCrumbling great idea! thanks

Comment: Oren, how badly do you need this addressed? If "money is no object", you could open a case with [Microsoft Support](https://support.serviceshub.microsoft.com/supportforbusiness)

Comment: This was the text of the mentioned semi-related deleted question: https://pastebin.com/cWtDB0D7

Comment: 8 years after the original post, we are still experiencing this issue from time to time. Even when RenderOptions.ProcessRenderMode is not set to RenderMode.SoftwareOnly...

Answer (score 2):

DirectX Rasterize (9 and above if I remember correctly) determine how the triangles are drawn. Given the three points of a triangle - you can draw them clockwise or anticlockwise, also you can determine if the surface of the triangles is facing inwards or outwards - that provides the intersection point.

It also provides the capability of setting Multisample and AntialiasedLine - those features (high process) allow the rendering of a much smoother lines. Remember that straight line don't really exists in a 2D screen - you might be familiar with the staircase effect in computer graphics or Jaggies.

Now when we use DirectX we are actually programming the GPU of the computer Graphic card. Therefor the graphic card must be DirectX ready - depends on the version off course.

Check your pc's hardware and determine whether the onbard or PCI graphics card are DirectX11 compliant.

Also you could adjust your WPF App rendering settings - tune it down if you will or switch it off all together at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/graphics-rendering-registry-settings?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

***More info:***

From the MSDN [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.renderoptions.processrendermode?view=netcore-3.1):

*Note* **ProcessRenderMode** specifies a preference and does not necessarily change the actual rendering mode. Other parts of the system may override this preference and force the system into software rendering.

You can check the system DirectX info by using dxdiag  in Window search box (Window 7 and above I think).

Comment: thanks for the answer. As I mentioned in one of my comments we are using SoftwareOnly rendering, so I don't know how GPU can be involved there at all. 
On the other hand, we don't use any drawing etc. in our app. This sounds like an internal WPF error when it is being used in SoftwareOnly mode. We want to understand what part can cause this and how can we fix it.

Comment: I see your update. But I don't see how we can fix the error.

Comment: Are you able to share the app - or a demo of the app?

Comment: It's quite big enterprise app, I don't think I can share it.

Comment: I fully understand - The only thing I can suggest is to set the SoftwareOnly in each windows that gets rendered - Or perhaps adding some logging to see where in the flow the exception is triggered -